# Data returned from an ajax call has the names of the database columns

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I need some help with returned data from Ajax call...
I'm using CodeIgniter framework for PHP and when I do an Ajax call, the response contains the column names of my database table...

Look: [image]

How do I change this?

Below is my code:

Controller:

```
$logStuff = $this->vpn_model->get_vpn_log();
echo json_encode($logStuff);
```

Model:

```
$this->db->select('connection_logevent, connection_logdate, connection_logip');
$this->db->from("connection_log");
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Look, I don't want the columns name of my database table to appear in the json array

Comment: Because whoever parses the json file in the browser will find out the name of the columns of the table from my database.

Comment: So you want to have array like `[['connection', '2017-01-16 01:01:01'], ['connection', '2017-01-16 01:01:01']]`?

Comment: Yes... Because that way hide the columns name...

Comment: I know that is a stupid question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if you return as ARRAY they can also known the column name. You can try this code then no one will know the column name if they parse the JSON:

```
$this->db->select('connection_logevent AS con_log_evnt, connection_logdate AS AS con_log_date, connection_logip AS con_log_ip');
$this->db->from("connection_log");
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: God, I feel so stupid. I completely forgot about that :(. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Thanks, don't worry i also do sometimes like that. :)

Comment: Since you're using PHP, you can create a Model class that maps your DB columns to names that you want to send to your front end. For example - email : emailAddress, first : firstName. You can then use your Model class as a middleware before you send your data to the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to iterate over you results and repack its data to new array:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = array($row['connection_logevent'], $row['connection_logdate'], $row['connection_logip']);
}
```

If you want to have it in the same structure but with different keys, you can also use aliases in query.

```
$this->db->select('connection_logevent AS field1, connection_logdate AS field2, connection_logip AS field3');
$this->db->from("connection_log");
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

Check [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html).

Comment: Thanks marian0. I'll use the aliases in my query!